# Datatable to div or something else?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

`enter code here`Hello, i have in my site a datatable to display ads (look at image )
  http://imageshack.com/a/img673/5302/id8xhB.png

I do not think that this is the best way cause i need something like e-shop items. exactly i need to displey my items and sorting it by asc or desc or views(i have view column to my db).

The table code in index.php

```
<table id="example" class="compact">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>1</th>
                        <th>2</th>
                        <th>3</th>
                        <th>4</th>
                        <th>5</th>
                        <th>6</th>

                    </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <?php
                $i=1;
                $z=0;
                include 'connection/search_arxiki.php';
                            while ($ad = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {


                            if (($z % 6) == 0){
                            echo "<tr>";
                            }
                            echo "<td>";?>
                            <center>
                            <a class="title" href="ad_show.php?id=<?php echo $ad['id']; ?>"><?php echo $ad['title']; ?>
                            <br>
                            <img src="<?php echo $ad['image']?>">
                            </a>
                            </center>
                            <?php echo "</td>";
                            if (($i % 6) == 0){
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            $i = $i + 1;
                            $z = $z + 1;
                            }
                ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I prefer something like javascript cause php will overload the server. 
Thank you for your opinions.

Comment: THIS TOPIC SOLVED :)

Answer (score 0):

You WILL need to have PHP somewhere. What you could possible do is, create a PHP page that handles request to the database and fetches rows and on the client side, you can make use of AJAX to fetch data from the PHP page. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('tbody').load('phppage.php');
});
```

And on click, you can just send data through ajax and update content.

There is no way you can avoid server-side code to achieve this.